# Tomcat configuration for Spring app

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, classloader, securitymanager

I have built web application for use in Tomcat. It depends on Spring. I have the following exception when trying to access it:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
```

I read tomcat docs, and found that I need to configure security. I added following lines to
"/usr/share/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy":

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/MyProject/-" {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission;
};
```

But it didn't help. To add, I installed Tomcat by pasting following [commands](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8541057):

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
cd /usr/share/tomcat6
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat6/conf conf
sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
sudo ln -s /var/log/tomcat6 log
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/tomcat6/conf
```

I have restarted server. The project exist in specified location.

What am I doing wrong?

I would really like to modify as few things on server as it is possible, without copying additional jars into servers lib folder.

---

My

Tomcat version = Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

Spring version = 3.0.1.RELEASE

---

The stack trace is too big to post it here, so please, follow [link](http://www.anywhereenterprises.com:80/1/1/a?a=dF&p=Y5isOWY5iqqzy7POAApQZOAAqqz) to see it.

---

Can anybody help me? To add, it is executed without exceptions on my Apache Geronimo.

Comment: I don't use Linux, but I've never had to modify Tomcat permissions to deploy Spring.  What exactly are you doing that requires this?  No such thing is necessary on Windows for Spring deployments.

Comment: I have several Spring based webapps running in Tomcat on Linux. No configuration change of this nature has been required.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Show the full stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use those symbolic links. Instead I would deploy at $CATALINA_BASE/webapps (check out /etc/init.d/tomcat6). Then in the policy file (/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/03catalina.policy):

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/lib/-" {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
};
```

Another option can be editing /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/04webapps.policy.

That worked for me some time ago.

Regards.